# Loading a Swift based UIViewController from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, interface-builder

I am attempting to load a view controller nib whose File's Owner is a Swift based UIViewController class. The view controller is very simple at this point--just a single label (`lblResult`) whose contents get set at runtime. When loading the view controller, I get the following error:

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lblResult
```

I know that this is usually because the File's Owner is not set in Interface Builder, however, in my case it IS set. I have verified that the IBOUtlet for `lblResult` is properly set and that the view property is also properly set. The only real difference here is that I am attempting to load the swift based view controller within an app written in Objective-C.

In my view controller class I am setting the UILabel property as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!
```

and setting its value as follows:

```
lblResult.text = "Time \(hour):\(minute):\(second)"
```

In my Obj-C calling class, I am instantiating the view controller as follows:

```
viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SwfViewController" bundle:nil];
```

The nib loads into view when no outlets are set, but when there are IBOutlets, i get the error. Any clues as to why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your nib is a View and the owner is a View Controller, make sure you connect your view controller's `view` property to the nib view. If your nib is a view controller, instead of setting the File Owner just set the `Custom Class` of the view controller to SwfViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Is this view controller present in your storyboard? If yes, you need to load the view controller by calling.

```
viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SwfViewController") as SwfViewController
```

Make sure you set the identifier of the view controller in the storyboard to SwfViewController.

The storyboard should look something like this.

[image]

Comment: The existing app does not use storyboards. I am researching to determine what it will take to integrate Swift into this app

Comment: In that case you need to add this to load the view controller: `viewController = SwfViewController(nibName: "SwfViewController", bundle: nil);`

Comment: Also make sure your SwfViewController has this method : `init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        // Custom initialization
    }`